# What is "ASST DEPT" in fully spelled out English?

Tags: meaning-in-context, acronyms, initialisms

It is difficult to use machine translation in order to translate abbreviations from English to Spanish when the words are not spelled correctly.

What is `ASST DEPT`  fully spelled out orthographically correct English?

Comment: You should be able to provide enough context to make it obvious whether the referent is a ***person*** or a ***department***. It's probably the former (most likely with the key word ***head*** either missing completely, or rendered as ***hd***), where the intended sense is the role ***Assistant Head of Department***. But so far as I know, that's not a "standard" abbreviation, in either commerce or academia.

Comment: I think this question can be easily answered by a dictionary: * https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/asst * https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dept

Comment: The word is probably *assistance" and not assistant.  departamento de asistencia Do you know what kind of assistance??

Answer (score -2):

`ASST DEPT` most often is an abbreviation of `ASSISTANT DEPARTMENT`.

Perhaps there exist dictionaries of standard American abbreviations of English words used in business. If so, I would hope that the dictionary would contain an entry for this term.

Comment: ASST is usually an abbreviation for _Assistant_, not _assist_. But it's normally part of a person's job title, so it doesn't really go with _Department_.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, you are correct. I do not know why I wrote, "`ASSIST DEPARTMENT`" instead of "`ASSISTANT DEPARTMENT`". I have edited the answer to incorporate your feedback. I have been comfortable using the word `ASSISTANT` for more than 20 years. I do not understand why I would make a careless mistake such as write "`ASSIST`" instead of "`ASSISTANT`". The original context was a job title `ASSISTANT DEPARTMENT LEADER`. `ASSISTANT DEPARTMENT` behaves like an adjective and modifies the noun `LEADER`.

Comment: What's this all about, 'Theodore Shepard'?

Comment: Translating "asst dept" gives "departamento asistente," which is the same result as if the abbreviation were spelled out. However, translating "assistant department chair," which seems to be the most likely context, instead produces "asistente del jefe del departamento." So, if you want to ensure your translation is accurate, it's important to provide the full context for the phrase. (Bizzarely, if I mistype the word "assistant" with 3 s's, "del" in the translation changes to "de.")

Comment: assistant department is meaingless in English...

Comment: In that case, _Assistant_ modifies the noun phrase _Department Leader_..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).